# No gpsd chronyd data exchange

Tags: beagleboneblack, ntp, gpsd

I want to run NTP server on my PocketBeagle with GPS and PPS as time source.
After configuration I can see that chronyd is getting data from PPS source but not from GPS.

```
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
#? GPS                           0   4     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
#* PPS0                          0   3   377     6  -2756ns[-4613ns] +/- 1656ns
```

Any ideas whats wrong or where should I start troubleshooting this?

Here is chrony.conf:

```
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1 10
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
commandkey 1
allow
refclock SOCK /run/chrony.ttyO4.sock refid GPS precision 1e-1 offset 0.9999 delay 0.2
refclock PPS /dev/pps0 refid PPS0 precision 1e-7 poll 3 trust
```

gpsd:

```
START_DAEMON="false"
USBAUTO="false"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
DEVICES = "/dev/ttyO4 /dev/pps0"
GPSD_OPTIONS=""
```

Comment: Please give more info...

Comment: I have some questions: 1) Is gpsd working on your BBB? 2) If so, where did you install it? Did you install it python3-gpsd or another form? pip3 install gpsd-py3 might be another method. Also...I am just needing more info. to gather what may be the issue. Run journalctl -xe and dmesg. If you would, relay the pastebin.com paste of those two messages from output of the command line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for showing interest. Reffering to 1) - Yes I belive it is working, checked with cgps and it is giving me normal data output. 2) `debian@beaglebone:$ which gpsd
/usr/sbin/gpsd`. To be honest I don't think i install another form of gpsd on my platform. Checked listed by you and did not found any of them on my PB. Here is data output from dmesg - https://pastebin.com/rhgTTdtX and journalctl -xe commands - https://pastebin.com/8JQ9cEZd

Comment: I have try to run it once again. I make sure that all gpsd and chronyd are stoped `systemctl stop gpsd` and `chrony` and processes are killed via `killall -9 gpsd chronyd` command, then used combination of commands found in documentation- https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_feeding_chrony_from_gpsd. Run ntpshmmon to check output but it seems like I only archive to get pps directly from gpio and pps via gpsd but not gps data - https://pastebin.com/YsSy8YTw

Comment: Here is cgps output - https://imgur.com/a/oaU3XrN

Comment: Hello andy0907: Did you try to use the file you are running as a non-root user and if you tried as root, please add the permissions. There are a bunch to pick from. You can either use letters or numbers for your permissions. I know sometimes my files, in this case a .c file, do not run on boot b/c of them not having permission from the root user or sudo, or my other user(s).

Comment: Also...do you have a .c file you are running w/out permissions? If so, do add permissions to it w/ chmod. If you do not have a .c file and are just using their examples, please say so. I will need to look them over.

Comment: How is your GPS installed on the BBB? UART, i2c, or other peripheral? Also...if you are using UARTs or UART2 for instance, use the uboot-overlay from the beagleboard.org peoples. They have an overlay to use called, say for /dev/ttyS2, BB-UART2-00A0.dtbo.

Comment: Before dropping privileges, gpsd will ensure that it has access to devices given to it on the command line by forcing their group read and write permissions on.

On a Linux with udev, check the files in /etc/udev/permissions.d to ensure that /dev/tty* devices are all created with the same group and with 0660 permissions             So...I got this from gpsd install portion on their website.

Comment: @DeFunct Thanks a lot for your suggestions and time. First, what I am trying to do is NTP server stratum 1 and for that I am using my PocketBeagle and GPS module. I am using here NEO-7M GPS. I connected it in same way D. Molloy did in his book: PB_UART4-Tx(P2.07)-GPS Rx | PB_UART4-Rx(P2.05) - GPS Tx. On this module I have also PPS signal which I connected to pin P2.04. I couldn't find pinout for pps in so i have add device overlay to do that on P2.04 pin. I have modified one from bb.org-overlays from github and use that.

Comment: Second, Today I reinstall my PB debian sw and try to configure once again everything from the bottom. Thought that maybe I messed up something. but I get the same result. Here I am attaching new `dmesg` run -  https://pastebin.com/A1Qy6xSq and bash `history` of used commands - https://pastebin.com/6axvxm22.

Comment: I don't understand last 6 lines from my new dmesg. For me it seems like `gpsd` or `chrony` executes some process and starts to treat my serial device as a new 'pps1' source. And thats why I am still getting two pps source (visible in ntpshmmon) and not gps.

Comment: Hello...okay. I think this GPS module might have more than four pins, i.e. is this true? I once got a NEO-8M GPS and could not get it to work b/c I got bored and my U-Blox worked out of the box. I will look up the info. for the NEO-7M GPS real quickly and get back to you.

Comment: I will need the exact model and datasheet. W/out that datasheet, we are guessing (sort of). Sort of may not be helpful. So, we should stick to the books. Right? So, please paste the mfg. of this NEO-7m GPS.

Answer (score 1):

I say give as much info. as you can on this issue. Also, I see that the `START_DAEMON=false` is an option in the configurations.

...

put it to `true`. I am really guessing here w/ little info. So, if someone downgrades my answer, I will take the 'punishment.'

If indeed you are using /dev/tty04, type it as /dev/ttyS4. And use the uboot-overlays section of the /boot/uEnv.txt file for updating your uboot-overlay.

Also...I will install it. If you have any source, please give it to me or just a portion. That way, I can see what exactly you are doing w/ your source.

I am not accomplished w/ the pps domain nor do I have any ideas for chrony but I will research it in time.

And...

I always used a .service file for starting my own service w/out a socket. Is that an option for your setup?

Comment: For instance...the info. I am looking for now is this idea: What exactly are you trying to do? Just run some gps daemon, in this case gpsd, w/ a window of openness to show you data while you record? Or...are you needing to use gpsd w/ this specific ntp client? I must be confused as to what exactly you are trying. Please type slowly to me. I can help but I need more info. and time.

Comment: This line changed togather with reinstallation. and right now it is `true` I have also try to run gpsd with `ttyS4` and no changes. I thinking about changing chrony to ntpd but need more time to do that. Dont really understand last sentence (about service file) gotta dig into that to understand.  I will try to make source avalible for you. As I write above I am trying to make NTP server with source of GPS module. I read about it and it seems like `gpsd+ntpd` or `chrony` is the best way to accomplish that. Link https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_time_service_daemon

Comment: Are you just wanting to run the GPS on boot? Or...do you just want to start GPS during specific times?